# passing java properties to scala - nosuchmethod errors

Tags: java, scala, properties

I'm attempting to compile some sample code from the Kafka [site](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example#). It's giving runtime errors when scala tries to read the java properties.

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.getShortInRange(VerifiableProperties.scala:83)
at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.getShort(VerifiableProperties.scala:59)
at kafka.producer.SyncProducerConfigShared$class.$init$(SyncProducerConfig.scala:49)
at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:51)
at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:56)
at Test_Producer.main(Test_Producer.java:28)
```

Here is the code snip in question. The error is coming from the `new ProducerConfig(props)` statement (line 28 above).

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("metadata.broker.list", "broker1:9092,broker2:9092");
props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
props.put("partitioner.class", "example.producer.SimplePartitioner");
props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
```

I tried stepping into the code in question and it appears that all the relevant values are set (IE getProperties is finding a value).

The code builds ok but perhaps I'm using an incorrect library?

Suggestions?

---

Edit:

Code is running (or supposed to) in Intellij 14.

Java is 1.8
Scala libraries are 2.11.6

---

Another data point: If I comment out all the properties except the first one ('broker1:9092...') I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.liftedTree1$1(ProducerConfig.scala:83)
at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:82)
at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:56)
at Test_Producer.main(Test_Producer.java:28)
```

Similar - but not quite the same. Still makes me think its a library issue.

Comment: Classpath problem? How do you run your code?

Comment: Isn't Kafka a Scala project? Was the version of Kafka you are using also compiled against Scala 2.11? This looks like a mismatch of scala-library version (like [this](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.kafka|kafka_2.11|0.8.2.1|jar))

Comment: Kafka is running on a different machine. Not sure how the versions would argue.  In any event - the kafka version is the latest. I'll try a downgrade on the local scala version and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this problem with below kafka POM dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.9.2</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.2.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Error Stack:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lscala/collection/immutable/StringOps;
    at kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties.getShortInRange(VerifiableProperties.scala:85)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducerConfigShared$class.$init$(SyncProducerConfig.scala:53)
    at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:51)
    at kafka.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.scala:56)
    at dominus.intg.jms.kafka.KafkaProducer.main(KafkaProducer.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Upgrade to 0.8.2.1, this issue is gone.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
   <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>0.8.2.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```